# Pandas groupby on multiple values

Tags: python, pandas

Start with a sorted table:

```
Index | A | B | C       |  
0     | A1| 0 | Group 1 |  
1     | A1| 0 | Group 1 |  
2     | A1| 1 | Group 2 |  
3     | A1| 1 | Group 2 |  
4     | A1| 2 | Group 3 |  
5     | A1| 2 | Group 3 |  
6     | A2| 7 | Group 4 |  
7     | A2| 7 | Group 4 |
```

Returns records 0,1,2,3,6,7

First I want to create groups based on Columns A and B.
Then I want only the first two subgroups of a Column A group returned.
I want all the records returned for the subgroup.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.factorize` within a `groupby` and filter for less than 2

```
df[df.groupby('A').B.transform(lambda x: x.factorize()[0]).lt(2)]
# same as
# df[df.groupby('A').B.transform(lambda x: x.factorize()[0]) < 2]

    A  B        C
0  A1  0  Group 1
1  A1  0  Group 1
2  A1  1  Group 2
3  A1  1  Group 2
6  A2  7  Group 4
7  A2  7  Group 4
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly. What is .lt()?

Comment: `A < B` is the same as `A.lt(B)`  I use it to clean up code... its a preference.  Thx for accepting.